# Python UnicodeDecodeError when hindering Python to convert JSON data to escaped special characters

Tags: python, json

This is my Python Code:

```
json_data = {
    "data":"ä"  
}

print (json_data)
# "data":"\xe4"

jsonified = json.dumps(json_data)
print (jsonified)
# same as above, "data":"\xe4"
```

How can I hinder Python or tell Json Dumps Method to not alter my special characters?

**Update**: After applying below suggestions I am getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Will move all my content out of SO anyway. Duplicate? Laughable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ensure_ascii=False`  then `encode('utf8')` :

```
jsonified = json.dumps(json_data,ensure_ascii=False ).encode('utf8')
print jsonified
```

Comment: what? i dont understand

Comment: read here https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage

Comment: thanks! now I am getting this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)